# How to add a shell command and use the result in a Fortran program?

Tags: shell, fortran

Is it possible to call shell command from a Fortran script?

My problem is that I analyze really big files. These files have a lot of lines, e.g. 84084002 or similar.
I need to know how many lines the file has, before I start the analysis, therefore I usually used shell command: `wc -l "filename"`, and than used this number as a parameter of one variable in my script.

But I would like to call this command from my program and use the number of lines and store it into the variable value.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Since 1984, actually in the 2008 standard but already implemented by most of the commonly-encountered Fortran compilers including `gfortran`, there is a standard intrinsic subroutine `execute_command_line` which does, approximately, what the widely-implemented but non-standard subroutine `system` does.  As @MarkSetchell has (almost) written, you could try

```
CALL execute_command_line('wc -l < file.txt > wc.txt' ) 
OPEN(unit=nn,file='wc.txt') 
READ(nn,*) count
```

What Fortran doesn't have is a standard way in which to get the number of lines in a file without recourse to the kind of operating-system-dependent workaround above.  Other, that is, than opening the file, counting the number of lines, and then rewinding to the start of the file to commence reading.

Comment: But it doesn't support bash like syntax like `[ -f test.txt ] && echo 'test.text file available'`, shows junky message with exitcode as nonzero

Answer (score 4):

You should be able to do something like this:

```
command='wc -l < file.txt > wc.txt' 
CALL system(command) 
OPEN(unit=nn,file='wc.txt') 
READ(nn,*) count
```

Comment: The `system` command is not standard fortran and should be avoided. Some compilers do not have it, others use `sh`. It is advised to use `EXECUTE_COMMAND_LINE`.

Answer (score 0):

You can output the number of lines to a file (fort.1)

```
 wc -l file|awk '{print $1}' > fort.1
```

In your Fortran program, you can then store the number of lines to a variable (e.g. count) by reading the file fort.1:

```
read (1,*) count
```

then you can loop over the variable count and read your whole file

```
do 1,count 
read (file,*)
```