# How to execute the bash command "export" within a Fortran program?

Tags: fortran, intel-fortran

I would like to execute the command `export $VAR=3` within a Fortran program. Unfortunately, the subroutine `system` cannot do it. Could you please help me how to perform the initialization of `VAR`? I am using ifort Version 11.1.

Comment: Which `fortran` are you using? `90` or `95` or Intel's one?

Comment: I am using fortran 95.

Comment: Do you know the answer?

Comment: I am not a "Fortran guy", so unfortunately I can't help you. The best thing I can do is to find some links for you. [This](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/26553245/how-to-add-shell-command-into-a-fortran-script) is simillar example that may help you.

Comment: I do not think you can define an environment variable in Fortran. You can get it https://gcc.gnu.org/onlinedocs/gfortran/GET_005fENVIRONMENT_005fVARIABLE.html but I don't think you can set it.

Comment: What do you want to achieve?  The "export" command most likely does not work as you need it to.

Comment: There is a program, called Gaussian, for which I make many input files with my Fortran program. But, during runntime this program requires environment variables to be set.

Comment: wrap your program (gaussian) in a shell script that sets up the environment and call that from fortran.

Answer (score 2):

One possible solution is to use a C routine from Fortran with the `iso_c_binding` intrinsic module. Through C you can set environment variables, which are then accessible to any program started by the Fortran program. This should work for most platforms and compilers.

**C routine**

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>     /* putenv, getenv */

void c_setgetenv ()
{
    char* p;
    putenv("x=100");
    p = getenv("x");
    if (p!=NULL)
        printf (" The variable is: %s\n",p);
}
```

**Fortran program**

```
program main
    use, intrinsic :: iso_c_binding
    implicit none

    ! The interface for the C routine
    interface
        subroutine c_setgetenv () bind(c)
            import ! use declarations from host (implicit none, iso_c_binding)
        end subroutine c_setgetenv
    end interface

    character(len=20) :: val

    !! begin
    call c_setgetenv()
    call get_environment_variable(name="x",value=val)
    print *, "Fortran: ", val
end program main
```

In this example, I haven't passed any args to the C routine from Fortran, but you can customize and handle that if needed. Note that you will need to compile and link the C object code to the Fortran program.

Answer (score 0):

In Intel Fortran you can use the non-standard extension `SETNVQQ` or call the appropriate operating system functions (Win API or POSIX).

There is no Fortran standard way.

It will only affect the current process and the child processes.

```
  character(20) :: val

  call setenvqq("x=5")
  call get_environment_variable(name="x",value=val)
  print *, val
  call execute_command_line("echo $x")
end
```

and

```
> ifort setenvqq.f90 
> ./a.out 
 5                   
5
```

Comment: I see you did not accept any answer before. I suggest you accept some of the answers you got for your other questions. For this question it is probably wise to wait for more possible answers.

Comment: So, will $VAR remain until my program will have been terminated?

Comment: No, it will not. You have to launch the other programs from your main program. There is no way how to keep it exported.